# Firefox Webdriver Instance 'Opens x2 Windows' instead of only 'x1 Window'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Firefox Webdriver Instance 'Opens x2 Windows' instead of only 'x1 Window'**

Any Ideas?

```
try {
    // Load the driver selected by user
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
    p.load(fi);

    String browserName = p.getProperty("browser");
    switch (browserName) {
        case "firefox":
            if (null == webdriver) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY );
                webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
                webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            break;
        case "chrome":
            if (null == webdriver) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY );
                webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your script and run it. Now step through your code line by line and see which lines create another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling `new FirefoxDriver()` twice.

Remove this line completely:

```
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```